# Match last for letters of a string with first four letters of another (SQL Pattern Matching)

Tags: sql, substring, impala

So If I have two tables:

```
**Table_1:**

F_name |L_Name

GREGORY| WASHINGTON


**Table_2:**

 ID_Key | Group_number

 9233443GREG| 193556
```

I want to match the last for digits of Table 2's ID_Key (GREG) with table 1's f_name (GREGORY).

So, I want the output to show all of the matches between the last 4 digits of ID_Key and first four digits of F_name.

Here is what I have tried but to no avail:

```
select * from 
Table_2 where
Where LEFT(ID_key,4) IN (
Select Left(F_name,4) from table_1
Group By LEFT (ID_KEY,4)
Having Count(*) > 1 
)
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: Question how large are the tables and which MySQL version (`SELECT VERSION()`) are you using?

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Answer (score 2):

Isn't simple as that?

```
select *
from table_1
    inner join table_2 on left(table1.f_name, 4) = right(table_2.id_key, 4);
```

Comment: a join operation seems to be the most straightforward way to satisfy the specification described in the question. +10

Comment: The left statement does not work. I am using impala. Would that make a difference?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know impala.  My query don't work as expected?

Answer (score 0):

use `right` in times of subtring of ID_key for 2nd table

```
select * from 
Table_2 where
Where right(ID_key,4) IN (
Select Left(F_name,4) from table_1

)
```

no need aggregation that you used in your query

output

```
ID_key        Group_number
 9233443GREG    193556
```

[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d36f5655b050135f4104838b5e027a45)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM [Table1] AS [t1]
INNER JOIN [Table2] AS [t2]
    ON LEFT(t1.[F_Name],4) = RIGHT(t2.[ID_key],4);
```

Answer (score 0):

We could use a join operation, and put the matching criteria into the `ON` clause something like this:

```
SELECT r.id_key
     , r.group_number
     , n.f_name
     , n.l_name
  FROM `Table_1` n
  JOIN `Table_2` r
    ON RIGHT(TRIM(r.id_key),4) = LEFT(n.f_name,4)
 ORDER
    BY r.id_key
     , r.group_number
     , n.f_name
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use EXISTS:

```
select * from Table_2 t2
where exists (
  select 1 from Table_1 
  where left(F_name, 4) = right(t2.ID_Key, 4)
)
```